# Is it possible to have SharePoint forms that are dynamic in their ability to adapt to user inputs?

Tags: list

My main question is to whether it is possible to have a list entry form adapt to a user's input? Effectively, I'm trying to implement a form that depending on your entry in the first few questions, you create a different data set than if you had chosen other options.

Does that functionality exist within SharePoint, or would it have to be custom built (if it's even possible)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is possible using InfoPath and SharePoint though it would really depend on how flexible you need the forms to be.  InfoPath also stresses functionality over aesthetics so the final forms might night have the exact look you are looking for. Infopath also requires that the users of the form also have InforPath installed in order to get the full functionality.  There is a web-based option for it but it does have slightly reduced capabilities.

If you are targeting SharePoint 2013, then the door is really wide open as literally anything can be used to create custom forms via the new AppWeb model.  This is still a very new area but the possibilities there are limitless.

Lastly, you could go the home-grown route and merely use the PageViewer web part in SharePoint to tie into your own custom Asp.Net solution that could use SharePoint Web Services for data storage.  This model is very close to what is done in SP 2013 anyway, though SP 2013 does have cleaner integration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create any type of HTML form you want and using either the COM or jQuery (with SPServices) push the data into a list.

Answer (score 0):

- You could use a survey for this for a basic solution.
- Infopath Forms might be a good solution and would be worth investigation.
- Nintex Forms could do this as well (3rd Party Tool)

Or custom development to do just about anything........